# C# DataGridView multiple filter

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview

I am trying to filter a DataGridView in C# (pretty new to this).
I tried many things but this is the closest i can get. It kinda works but it filters out some columns incorrectly and i don't understand why.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Filter = "";

                int i;
                bool isnum = int.TryParse(txtSearch.Text, out i);
            
                if (isnum == true)
                {
                    Filter = "TicketNumber like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR ";
                    //(dataGridView_View.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("TicketNumber like '*" + txtSearch.Text) + "*'";
                }

        Filter = Filter +
        "Status like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "Title like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "AssignedTo like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "Dept like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "ProjectNumber like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "Client like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR " +
        "Category like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";


        (dataGridView_View.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter;
        MessageBox.Show(Filter);
     }
```

Here is what the Messagebox shows when i insert "D" in the search textbox:

[image: Query]

But I know it's not working properly because i can see it filters out more than it should.

Any ideas are welcome!

EDIT1: Here are more information. Here's the form, where you can see some data. Focus on the 4 first lines, first column:
[image]

Here is what I get when I put the search for "URG":
[image]

My goal is to have some kind of a "Search". If what's found in the textbox is found in any cell, I want the whole row to be displayed.

Comment: Without knowing the input and expected output it is hard to know why your filter is not doing what you want.

Comment: I could be mistaken; however, it seems odd to “filter” ALL the fields with the same term. Can you show an example of where a row is improperly filtered? From what I can decipher, in your current example, if “any” of the fields contain a “d”, then the row should be displayed. Can you show an example of this where a row contains the filter term, yet is not displayed?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure, you cannot use “like” with numbers. It is unclear what the data type each field is, however, if “TicketNumber” or “ProjectNumber” are numeric types in the table, then, “like” will most likely throw an error or give unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am willing to do some kind of a "search". If the term "WISH" is somewhere in any row, i want the row to be displayed. I'll put more information in a sec.

Comment: From what I can see… the “Priority” field is NOT one of the filter items. So, it makes sense that some may not be displayed since the filter never uses the “Priority” field in the filter. Is the filter supposed to include the “Priority” column in the filter?

Comment: "Facepalm"... Went too fast... Thanks for your help. It works flawlessly...